# Animate with draw-move for loop in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create an on-screen animation for iOS with Swift 4 on the Xcode IDE by drawing an object to the screen, waiting, adjusting the object's location, and redrawing.  However, when I do this inside of a for loop, the screen simply waits and then draws the object in the final position.  Why is it doing this?  How can I animate the way that I want to?  Is there an alternative way to animate that I should be considering?

My code is here:

```
var counter = 0
for n in 0...10{
    counter = counter + 1
    draw_wheel(counter)
    sleep(1)
}
```

I simply see the object I am trying to draw in its final orientation after 10 seconds.

Comment: `sleep(1)` is blocking the thread, making all UI updates (and everything else) stop until the timer is done, and all iterations of your loop finish.

Comment: What can I do instead, then?

Comment: Don’t use a loop. Start a [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer) and update your UI in the handler.

Comment: By the way, rather than updating it, every second, if you’re just animating its position, maybe you just want to use some of the built in animation techniques to adjust its position for you. It will smoothly animate the transition of the object as it moves across the screen rather than jumping once every second. It depends upon the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create step by step animation over the time, you should consider to use [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) instead of Timers or loops.

Basically CADisplayLink is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display and draw according to timestamp.

```
func createDisplayLink() {
    let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                    selector: #selector(step))

    displaylink.add(to: .current,
                    forMode: .default)
}

@objc func step(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
    print(displaylink.timestamp)
}
```